# md5 hash - расшифровка

Tags: md5

Нужно расшифровать MD5 hash, думаю что это именно он, сохраненный в базе данных, в язык понятный для человека.

```
72e2713d681430c2396567582a211a93
```

Comment: С доступной вам вычислительной мощностью, как вам ответили, ваша задача невыполнима.  Быстрый поиск по готовым словарям вашего хеша не нашел, радужные таблицы бесполезны, если хеш правильно посолен.

Comment: Возможно это слово "гладиолус" + какая-то соль.

Comment: мне фраза "какая-то соль" понравилась :) с точки зрения отображения бесконечного пространства солей хорошей хеш функцией можно получить _любой_ хеш и вместо гладиолус может быть _любое_ слово :)

Comment: Расшифровка: `gt@center`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MD5 - алгоритм необратимого шифрования, это класс алгоритмов, в которых невозможно восстановить исходную зашифрованную последовательность. Как правило, осуществляется сравнение самих MD5-хэшей, это позволяет вообще не хранить секретную информацию, например, пароль пользователя, в открытом виде.

Comment: md5 это не шифрование. Шифрование допускает однозначную расшифровку (если знать все "алгоритмы" и "секреты"). md5 это "хэширование".